# Guid to Base64 in Java

Tags: java, base64, uuid

I am converting a Guid to Base64 in C# using the following code:

```
var id = Guid.Parse("be9f1bb6-5c8e-407d-85a3-d5ef31f21b4d");
var base64=Convert.ToBase64String(id.ToByteArray());
```

**Output**

> thufvo5cfUCFo9XvMfIbTQ==

When I try to do the same in Java using the following:

```
java.util.Base64.Encoder encoder=Base64.getEncoder();
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("be9f1bb6-5c8e-407d-85a3-d5ef31f21b4d");
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
encoder.encodeToString(bb.array());
```

**Different output**

> vp8btlyOQH2Fo9XvMfIbTQ==

What I am doing wrong in my Java code? How can I get the same result I am getting using C#?

Comment: Why do you need to parse it into a UID first?

Comment: tried to convert it from string, I got totally different result

Comment: Why should Guid.parse() and UUID.fromString() generate the same result? Is this defined somewhere?

Comment: ```bb.array()``` and ```id.ToByteArray()``` are not the same.

Comment: Guid of C# and UUID of Java is not same! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745512/how-to-read-a-net-guid-into-a-java-uuid) might help you!

Comment: Also additional backgroud gives an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17310081/283828) to this question: [Is there any difference between a GUID and a UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246930/is-there-any-difference-between-a-guid-and-a-uuid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure is a bit different, but swapping some bytes in the first part of the byte array fixes your problem.

```
java.util.Base64.Encoder encoder= Base64.getEncoder();
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("be9f1bb6-5c8e-407d-85a3-d5ef31f21b4d");
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());

byte[] uuid_bytes = bb.array();
byte[] guid_bytes = Arrays.copyOf(uuid_bytes,uuid_bytes.length);

guid_bytes[0] = uuid_bytes[3];
guid_bytes[1] = uuid_bytes[2];
guid_bytes[2] = uuid_bytes[1];
guid_bytes[3] = uuid_bytes[0];
guid_bytes[4] = uuid_bytes[5];
guid_bytes[5] = uuid_bytes[4];
guid_bytes[6] = uuid_bytes[7];
guid_bytes[7] = uuid_bytes[6];

String result = encoder.encodeToString(guid_bytes);
```

Comment: It seems that .NET uses a non-standard bit order. Maybe it will be helpful for somebody: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10190817/632199 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16722909/632199

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Encoding "Many systems encode the UUID entirely in a big-endian format." "Other systems, notably Microsoft's marshalling of UUIDs in their COM/OLE libraries, use a mixed-endian format, whereby the first three components of the UUID are little-endian, and the last two are big-endian."